# Contact form don't send Email

Tags: contact

I just recently created a website with Wordpress and I've added a contact form, I used the plugin Contact Form 7. Except, it does not send email to the administrator when applying the form.

What do you think ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1. Does it go to a junk folder? 2. Do you get any errors? 3. Is this live or local?

Comment: please see this detailed [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/326417/transferring-contact-form-input-to-an-email-account-without-using-an-email-proxy/327338#327338).

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's because SPF misconfiguration.

> SPF allows the owner of an Internet domain to specify which computers are authorized to send mail with sender addresses in that domain, using Domain Name System (DNS) records. Receivers verifying the SPF information in TXT records may reject messages from unauthorized sources before receiving the body of the message. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)

You can install plugin which allows you sending emails through SMTP using your mail account. Configuration should be as simple as configuring e-mail client like Outlook or Thunderbird. You can use for example this plugin: [Easy WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/).